# Unitary structures on fusion categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, subfactors, fusion-categories, modular-tensor-categories, unitary-fusion-category

A unitary fusion category is a fusion category with a $C^*$-tensor structure.
Hence, in principle, a fusion category could have more than one unitary structure. Does exist a fusion category with more than one (non equivalent) unitary structures.

Unitarity is equivalent to the existence of basis such that the $F$-matrices are unitary. This property is to be unitarizible. The question in matricial terms is: suppose that you have two different basis such that the $F$-matrices are unitary, Can be unitary gauged one basis in the other? or in oher words, there exist always unitary change of basis from one basis to the other basis?

---

[added by A. Henriques]
I see in the comments that there is some confusion in the interpretation of the question, so let me attempt a reformulation:

> Is every equivalence $F:\mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ between unitary fusion categories naturally equivalent to a unitary equivalence (i.e., one which is a dagger functor)

I see that Galindo-Hong-Rowell have some results in that direction
(see $\S$5.5, on page 21 of his [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5048v1.pdf)), but they don't exactly addresses this question.

Comment: I am curious about this, too. I guess there are also fusion categories without a $\mathrm{C}^\ast$-tensor structure, what goes wrong there?

Do you happen to have a reference where the notion of a "unitary fusion category" is used (or even better) introduced? How would I call a MTC which is $\mathrm{C}^\ast$?


Comment: There are many places with the definition of unitary fusion category, for example http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/1209.2022 The MTC with a C^*-tensor structure are called unitary MTC.

An example of a non-unitary fusion category is the Yang-Lee category. The problem is that every unitary fusion category is pseudo-unitary in the sense of http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203060. In fact, an other natural question (I guess it in ENO): Is every pseudo-unitary fusion category a unitary fusion category?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I think that if a unitary structure exists then it's unique.  This is because unitarity should be equivalent to saying that the F-matrices can be gauged to become unitary matrices, and that's a condition not a structure.

Comment: Yes, you are right, unitarity is equivalent to the existence of a basis such that the F-matrices are unitary. This property is to be unitarizible. 
The question in matricial terms is: suppose that you have two different basis such that the F-matrices are unitary, Can be unitary gauged one basis in the other? or in oher words, there exist always a unitary change of basis from one basis to the other basis?  

Comment: But isn't that just polar decomposition?  That is to say, if you can conjugate one unitary by $X$ to get another, then you can also get between them by conjugating by the unitary matrix $X \sqrt{X X^\dagger}^{-1}$?

Comment: @André: Thanks! It exactly that I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Reutter's recent paper "uniqueness of unitary structure for unitarizable fusion categories" answers your question in the affirmative (link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.09710.pdf).